# Write Array To Table

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

I am trying to write a function to output the data that is in a 2D array to an empty table.

```
Function WriteArrayToTable(InputArray() As Variant, TableName As String, SheetName As String)
    Dim MyTable As ListObject: Set MyTable = Worksheets(SheetName).ListObjects(TableName)
    MyTable.DataBodyRange.Value = InputArray
End Function
```

However, I get an object variable not set on the second line. I've tried the various permutations of including and excluding Set and DataBodyRange.Value. When I set my watches, it can find MyTable just fine and InputArray is the appropriate size however MyTable.DataBodyRange is Nothing.

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/01/09/finding-the-next-row-in-a-listobject-in-vba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Function WriteArrayToTable(InputArray() As Variant, TableName As String, SheetName As String)
    Dim MyTable As ListObject: Set MyTable = Worksheets(SheetName).ListObjects(TableName)
    Dim target As Range 'helper var for output point
    With MyTable
        If .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            ' table is empty: output point - under the header
            Set target = .HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1)
        Else
            ' table not is empty: output point - at the end of the table
            Set target = .DataBodyRange.Cells(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1)
        End If
        target.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(InputArray, 1), UBound(InputArray, 2)).Value = InputArray
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed, when a Table is empty, `DataBodyRange` is `Nothing`.

When that is the case, use [InsertRowRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.insertrowrange) instead

```
If MyTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    MyTable.InsertRowRange = ...
Else
    `...
End If
```

Comment: InsertRowRange is also Nothing.

Comment: I've tested this.  `InsertRowRange ` is _not_ Nothing when `DataBodyRange ` is Nothing.  This is also confirmed in the link Tim posted under the Q

Answer (score 0):

### Write an Array to a Table

- It is assumed that the array has the same number of columns as the table.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteArrayToTable( _
        ByVal InputArray As Variant, _
        ByVal TableName As String, _
        ByVal SheetName As String)
    Dim MyTable As ListObject
    Set MyTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).ListObjects(TableName)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(InputArray, 1)
    MyTable.HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(srCount).Value = InputArray
    With MyTable.DataBodyRange
        Dim drCount As Long: drCount = .Rows.Count
        If drCount > srCount Then
            .Resize(drCount - srCount).Offset(srCount).Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen: I wrote the `InputArray` already to the table using the `HeaderRowRange`?

Comment: Never mind, hadn't tested my idea. You're right, the table automatically resizes so that `DataBodyRange` is not nothing after writing the array.